# ASP.NET - Pages that allow multiple users to interact with each other

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to have users on a new site be able to interact with each other.  I thought searching for sample code for async controllers would help, but I can't really seem to find much.

I guess I am trying to replicate Node.js/Meteor like interactions where an action one user performs can be shown to other users.  I assume this would work using async controllers and ajax, but I have found very little documentation and examples.  I'm starting to think this isn't something that can happen in ASP.NET.

Sorry this is such a general question.

Comment: This question is entirely too general.  However, do some research into  [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr), I believe it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, you might consider having a look at [SignalR ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/signalr). Here you will be able to update the content on each browser window. Secondly you might need to have a look at Ajax request. They also do the same work. But you mentioned the ASP.NET, so the SignalR will be better!

Answer (score 0):

Watch [Building Real-time Web Apps with ASP.NET SignalR](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034), this video is by the creators of SignalR.

I think this will give you an idea of how SignalR might be the framework you want to use for your idea to build an application where multiple users can interact within a single page.